# Need to format fieldname of structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, struct

I have field name which contains (.) for matlab structure

When I create structure, it throws invalid field name error

e.g

```
fieldName = 'Freq.01'
```

Structure

```
s.(fieldName) = 25;
```

Comment: Valid field names begin with a letter, and can contain letters, digits, and underscores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`matlab.lang.makeValidName`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) to convert an invalid name such as `'Freq.01'` into something that is a valid name. (This is only available in relatively recent versions of MATLAB).

In older versions of MATLAB, you can use [`genvarname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html).

Comment: Thanks, Do you have idea, whether it is available in MATLAB version R2010b SP1

Comment: In R2010b, use `genvarname`.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in Yuans's comment, fieldnames must not contain '.'. This may be the case because the Value of a field can be another field. Maybe you want to replace the '.' with '_' and then use your new valid fieldname:

```
fieldname = 'Freq.01';
fieldname = strrep(fieldname, '.', '_');
s.(fieldname) = 25
s.('hello').('world') = 17
```